# How to store class members to be exposed to Boost.Python

Tags: c++, boost, boost-python

I need to store a list of class members to be exposed to Python later on.

I'd like to go from :

```
struct Toto {
    int one;
    double two;
};

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(PythonExport)
{
    using namespace boost::python;

    class_<Toto>("Toto")
        .def_read("one", &Toto::one)
        .def_read("groot", &Toto::two);
}
```

To :

```
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(PythonExport)
{
    using namespace boost::python;

    std::map<std::string, ???> fieldList;
    fieldList.push_back("one", &Toto::one);
    fieldList.push_back("two", &Toto::two);
    RegisterFields(class_<Toto>("Toto"), fieldList);
}

template <class T>
void RegisterFields(class_<T> aClass, std::map<std::string, ...> fieldList) {
    for(fields : fieldList) {
        aClass.def_read(fieldList.first, fieldList.second);
    }
}
```

My only constraints is that it has to be storable in a container (map). It can be stored in a templated class under an interface if needed but i'd like to avoid that (performances)

Comment: I suppose by `def_read` you mean `def_readonly` (as I don't see the former in the docs/code)? | What else do you intend to do with the container? Does it need to be a map? | What problem does this intend to solve (I've got an idea, but wanna see if it's worth the effort and added complexity)? | What performance issues are you worried about?

Comment: Yes `def_readonly` sorry. Not it doesn't need to be a map. Some objects are already described for serialization using internal macros. I'd like to upgrade those macro to use it for python bindings as well, that's why i'd like to store the list of fields in a container to be able to use them later.

Comment: And there are no performance contraints for now

Comment: Well, here's the first attempt: https://pastebin.com/yFqGfwTQ

Comment: Any comments? Does this meet your needs?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you